# The compiler is unable to type-check expression Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, swift5

I am having trouble when trying to compile my code as this error keeps appearing:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

Here is the section of the code where the error appears:
[image]

Any ideas on how I can get the code to compile and clear this error?

Comment: is there a reason why your parameters are double optionals?

Comment: If removing the double optionals doesn't help you might need to use local variables, `let status = status ?? self.status` etc. Basically the error message tells you what you should do.

Comment: Do not (just) show pictures of code. Show actual code, as text. And show enough of it (including the declaration of Council) that we can reproduce the issue ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to split your expressions into many expressions for example try replacing:

```
return Council(status: status ?? self.status,
council : council ?? self.council,
year: year ?? self.year,
councilRating: councilRating ?? self.councilRating,
annualChange: annualChange ?? self.annualChange,
councilTax: councilTax ?? self.councilTax)
```

With:

```
let s = status ?? self.status
let c = council ?? self.council
let y = year ?? self.year
let cr = councilRating ?? self.councilRating
let ac = annualChange ?? self.annualChange
let ct = councilTax ?? self.councilTax


return Council(status: s,
council : c,
year: y,
councilRating: cr,
annualChange: ac,
councilTax: ct)
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks Marc